# Have values inserted into textarea bypass required checks

Tags: javascript, css, html, textarea

Currently, I have an (HTML5) input tag as follows:

```
<input name='email' class='textarea' type='textarea' onblur='if(this.value==""){ this.value = "Email address...";}' onfocus='this.value="";' value='Email address...' required></input>
```

This is all well and good for my current needs, but with the default values (or any inserted values) the 'required' check thinks that everything's sweet because the input boxes are populated. This isn't terribly great if a user were to click the sign in button with the details "Email address...". It just won't log them in, yes, but I want to stop them from being able to sign in with a default value in the first place. Hence, my question:

Is there any way to apply 'required' status to the input box onblur (through javascript, css, html, or other means), or to make certain input box values bypass the 'required' check?

I was thinking about uses CSS to apply text to the input box, like

```
input.textarea{
    content: "Email address...";
}

input.textarea:focus{
    content: "";
}
```

but as far as I can tell, content doesn't apply anything to input boxes (or if it does, the input box renders above the text).

I could remove the values entirely, and place the labels outside the input boxes, but that doesn't really fit in with the design of the website I'm currently producing, and is probably a last resort choice (if I even consider it a choice at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `placeholder` attribute.

```html
<form><input name='email' class='textarea' type='textarea' placeholder="Email address..." required></input>
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Note: Don't use `value` attribute because when values are given, it is considered as the field has value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a placeholder for this purpose.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Your description here...">
```